# I lost props after reloading the page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reload, prop

I used axios in useEffect of my wrapper component and I sent the data as props to the other component "singleQuestionnaire", in singleQuestionnaire component, I destructured the data, in the first try, it works fine, but after reloading the page it doesn't work with an error : can not read property "map" of undefined

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SingleQuestionnaire from "./SingleQuestionnaire";
import { fetchQuestions } from "../../../api/index";

const Questionnaires = ({ match }) => {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);
  const pid = match.params.id;
  const getQuestionnaire = async (pid) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await fetchQuestions(pid);
      console.log(data.data, "action in component");
      setQuestions(data.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuestionnaire(pid);
  }, []);
  console.log("all questions", questions);

  return (
    <div>
      <SingleQuestionnaire questions={questions} setQuestions={setQuestions} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Questionnaires;
```

and this is my singleQuestionnaire component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const SingleQuestionnaire = ({ questions, setQuestions }) => {
  const [questionnaire, setQuestionnaire] = useState([]);
  console.log(questions);
  const { data } = questions;
  console.log("data", data.farmInformationQuestionnaireData);
  return <div>simple component</div>;
};

export default SingleQuestionnaire;
```

For the first time, in console I can see the data "data.data.farmInformationQuestionnaireData". It's an array but for the second time it's undefind.

Comment: You can use history.push() to add pid to url and move getQuestionnaire function inside singleQuestionnaire component and take pid from url with useLocation

Answer (score 0):

because questions in `SingleQuestionnaire` is an empty array before we fetch
which causes an error here

```
  const { data } = questions;
```

you can add a loading text because initially `questions` will be an empty array then it will be your `res.data` (assuming it's an object)

```
const SingleQuestionnaire = ({ questions, setQuestions }) => {


  const [questionnaire, setQuestionnaire] = useState([]);
  console.log(questions);

  if(questions.length === 0 ) return <h1> Loading</h1>

  const { data } = questions; 
  console.log("data", data.farmInformationQuestionnaireData);
  return <div>simple component</div>;
};
```

Comment: in this component, I use useEffect, too and when I put if statement and return something I got error "React hook should be before return but i need useEffect after this if statement

Comment: @ZahraEsmaili can you update your code then ? because i don't see useEffect in SingleQuestionnaire

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because of the async API call. When you make an async call, the thread does not wait, it moves on and it starts executing other things.
Now your async call might be complete but your callback will not be executed until the stack is empty, that's just how javaScript works. I recommend you use some kind of loader gif or text

```
 {questions ? <SingleQuestionnaire questions={questions} setQuestions={setQuestions} /> : <p>Loading...</p>}
```